# How should I design my database for Point of Sale system?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, mvvm, database-design

I'm developing a new **WPF** & **MVVM** & **EF (Code First)** application to build a Point of Sale system for one of my customers. I've taken a look to guides on the web and here. But I'm still confusing about how the database design should be?

I've found a good example of the design that I've mentioned which is [this project](https://github.com/VladTsiukin/AirlineTicketOffice). But I'm kinda worried about the extensibility and quality.

I'm thinking to build the scheme like this:

```cs
    [Table("Customer")]
    public partial class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FullName => FirstName + " " + LastName;
        ...
    }

    [Table("Category")]
    public partial class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        ...
    }

    [Table("Brand")]
    public partial class Brand
    {
        public int BrandId { get; set; }
        public string BrandName { get; set; }
        ...
    }

    [Table("Product")]
    public partial class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int BrandId { get; set; }
        public decimal ListPrice { get; set; }
        ...
    }

    [Table("Stock")]
    public partial class Stock
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        ...
    }

    [Table("Order")]
    public partial class Order
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public int OrderStatus { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        ...
    }

    [Table("OrderItem")]
    public partial class OrderItem
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal ListPrice { get; set; } 
        ...
    }
```

What kind of problems may arise If I use a scheme like this? Or Is there a point about the scheme I should take care of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks pretty good and simple to me. I have only two comments:

1. It's common for a product to belong to more than one category. You can achieve this by adding another table relating products to categories.
2. Stock has a 1:1 relationship with Product, so really you could put the fields for Stock under Product, unless there is something hiding in your "..." that would necessitate them being separated.

Comment: First of all your first comment made me really feel comfortable about the process. Cause I was kinda nervous about the production scenario. And for the second comment, actually, I was planning to add "Store" table which means more than one place to sell items. And the "Stock" table will have "StoreId". So I'm thinking to track the quantity at stores with this way. And one more thing, Will backend layer encounter some problems because of not filtering orders by stores? (It's a request)

Comment: That makes sense. If you think in the future you would have a reason to relate an order to a store, then I'd add the store id to the order now. Presumably you would be taking stock from the same store where the order is placed, to that would be a useful relationship to establish.